# Testing of shiny modules containing other modules

Tags: r, testing, shiny

In a large Shiny App, I have a lot of modules within other modules. These nested modules also sometimes have input controls, e.g. `textInput()` or `actionButton`, which trigger certain events also in the parent module.

The following MWE shows the problem.
The module `summaryServer` prints a summary of a value, but waits for the reactive from `rangeServer`, which is triggered by a button. I want a [Testing](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.5.0/testServer.html) specific for `summaryServer` with `testServer()` function from Shiny, but how can I "click" the Button in the contained `rangeServer` module to continue? Is that something about the Mock Shiny Session?

```r
### TESTING ###
x <- reactiveVal(1:10)
testServer(summaryServer, args = list(var = x), {

  cat("var active?", d_act(),"\n")

  # -----------------------------
  # How to click "go" here?
  # -----------------------------

  
  cat("var active?", d_act(), "\n")
})
```

```r
### The app ###
summaryUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    textOutput(NS(id, "min")),
    textOutput(NS(id, "mean")),
    textOutput(NS(id, "max")),
    rangeUI(NS(id, "range"))
  )
}
summaryServer <- function(id, var) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(var))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
  
    d_act = reactiveVal("Haha nope")
    range_val = rangeServer("range", var = var)
    
    # waits to range_val
    observeEvent(range_val(),{
      d_act("TRUE")
      message(range_val())
      output$min <- renderText(range_val()[[1]])
      output$max <- renderText(range_val()[[2]])
      output$mean <- renderText(mean(var()))
    })
  })
}

rangeUI = function(id) {
  textInput(inputId = NS(id, "go"), label = "Go")
}
rangeServer = function(id, var){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
   # when button gets clicked
    eventReactive(input$go,{
      range(var(), na.rm = TRUE)
      
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE, ignoreNULL = TRUE)
  })
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  summaryUI("sum")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  x = reactiveVal(1:10)
  summaryServer("sum", x)
}

# shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a tricky one. It works if you set both `ignoreInit` and `ignoreNULL` to `FALSE` but just because then you are not initially dependent on a change of `go` anymore, which is undesirable.

I do not think it is possible to change `go` inside of `rangeServer` when running `testServer` with `summaryServer`. You can however use `{shinytest}` to achieve this. Note that here you invoke and test the entire app. Therefore, when using modules, you have to call elements by their complete id, including namespaces.

(I changed `go` to an `actionButton`, everything else stays the same)

```
rangeUI <- function(id) {
  actionButton(inputId = NS(id, "go"),label = "Go")
}
```

```
test_that("output updates when reactive input changes", {

  # invoke app
  app <- shinytest::ShinyDriver$new("app.R")

  # initially, the button has`nt been clicked and the outputs are empty
  testthat::expect_equal(app$getValue("summary-range-go"), 0)
  testthat::expect_equal(app$getValue("summary-min"), "")

  # click the button
  app$click("summary-range-go")
  testthat::expect_equal(app$getValue("summary-range-go"), 1)
  # testthat::expect_equal(app$getValue("summary-min"), "1")

  # for some reason, the button value increased, hence is clicked,
  # but the outputs have not been triggered yet.
  # another click fixes that
  app$click("summary-range-go")
  testthat::expect_equal(app$getValue("summary-min"), "1")

})
```